# Error on upload file using league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 on Laravel into Minio

Tags: laravel, minio, flysystem

I have error when trying to upload files to Minio object-storage server (something similar to AWS S3).
My endpoint is using hostname such as example.com, and the bucket is "mybucket".
But when I upload file I got error like this :

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "http://mybucket.example.com/?prefix=xxxx&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: mybucket.example.com
```

It seem the lib adding bucket-name in front of server hostname, so it will error on resolving hostname. But this error not happened when I hit upload to the server IP-Address.

Currently I'm using league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:1.0.29
PHP 7.3.9
Laravel 7.2

Answer (score 4):

Currently the default config is bucket name as subdomain. If you want to use subdirectory style as bucket name, you can use `'use_path_style_endpoint' => true` in your config or when manually init `S3Client` object. You can read related Minio config here:

- https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-php-with-minio-server.html
- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#configuring-minio